# How to attach an event handler to a dynamically created item in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and am trying to add an onClick event handle to a list item which is created using `map`.

Currently, the page renders with the individual items each having their own button.  However, when i click on any of the button an error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'AddThisToReadingList' of undefined`.

Any help would be appreciated in understanding what is happening.  Thanks in advance.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class ResultsList extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      currentUserEmail: 'brad.ga.co',
      currentBookId: {}
    }
  }

  AddThisToReadingList(index){
    console.log('this');
    //set state
    //axios request to get book info
    //send to node update user
  }

  render(){
    console.log('Rendering');
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          <ListedBooks data ={this.props.listFromGoogle}/>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

const ListedBooks= props =>{
  if (props.data === undefined){
    return (<div>Loading....</div>)
  }

  return(
    props.data.map( (book, index)=>{
      return <li key={index}>
        <h4>Title: {book.volumeInfo.title}</h4>
        <div>Author: {book.volumeInfo.authors.map((element, index)=> <p key={index}>{element}</p>)}</div>
        <p>Description: {book.volumeInfo.description}</p>
        <p>Release Date: {book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}</p>
        <img src={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}/>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={()=>this.AddThisToReadingList(index)}>Add to my reading list</button>
      </li>
    })
  )
}




export default ResultsList;
```

Comment: Try `<ListedBooks data={this.props.listFromGoogle} AddThisToReadingList={this.AddThisToReadingList}/>` then, in your `map`, `<button onClick={()=>props.AddThisToReadingList(index)}>`. `this` is `undefined` inside `ListedBooks`.

Comment: you AddThisToReadingList function is in another class. What are you doing?

Comment: I left out `.bind(this)` in my previous comment, but added it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

In `ResultsList`:

```
<ListedBooks
  data={this.props.listFromGoogle}
  AddThisToReadingList={this.AddThisToReadingList.bind(this)}
/>
```

In `ListedBooks`:

```
<button onClick={()=>props.AddThisToReadingList(index)}>
  Add to my reading list
</button>
```

`ListedBooks` knows nothing about `this` in `ResultsList`. `this` is, in fact, `undefined` in `ListedBooks`. You need to pass the method to `ListedBooks` as a prop in order to access it there.

Comment: Thankyou for the code, but more importantly the explanation Tex.  Working!

Answer (score -2):

Add additional data to button like

```
<button id="additem" data-index={index}></button>
```

Then you can add listener with native javascript

```
render() {
  const button = document.getElementById('additem');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.AddThisToReadingList(button.dataset.index);
  })

  return (
      props.data.map( (book, index)=>{
        return <li key={index}>
                 <h4>Title: {book.volumeInfo.title}</h4>
                 <div>Author: {book.volumeInfo.authors.map((element, index)=> <p key={index}>{element}</p>)}</div>
                 <p>Description: {book.volumeInfo.description}</p>
                 <p>Release Date: {book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}</p>
                 <img src={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}/>
                 <br/>
                 <button data-index={index}>Add to my reading list</button>
               </li>
        })
    )
 }
```